# Getting multiple returns on distinct selection

Tags: sql

This is going to look like a mess. I have a request for multiple tables to output into one spreadsheet. I'm still new at this and have only really used inner joins before. Here's what my SQL looks like:

```
select distinct (o.objectnumber), g.locale, g.locus, g.excavation, g.mapreferencenumber,
case when t.texttypeid like '9' then t.textentry end,
case when f.userfieldid like '25' then f.fieldvalue end
from objects o
   inner join TextEntries t on t.id = o.objectid
   inner join ObjGeography g on g.ObjectID = o.objectid
   inner join userfieldxrefs f on f.id = o.objectid
   inner join PackageList pl on o.objectID = pl.ID
   inner join Packages p on pl.PackageID = p.PackageID
where p.packageid like '8502'
order by g.mapreferencenumber asc
```

I know, it's a mess right? It's giving me the correct output, but is also creating multiple rows with the same data. I've done some googling on this and have seen some remarks about outer joins, but I'm not sure how to correctly apply this to my statement. Any ideas?

Sorry; I got called away and just now had a chance to check on this. It's my first question and I guess I didn't really understand what you guys needed to see in order to understand what I wanted. It looks like the group by function will work best, I had seen this when researching the statement, but didn't understand how to properly implement it. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you provide a sample output from this query

Comment: Don't just dump query, and expect us to understand what you want.  Which dbms???  What do you want???  Where's sample input???  Where's expected output???  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You could just add a DISTINCT/GROUP BY all columns to get rid of the duplicates. But it depends on what you are trying to do. In general you want to understand why you are getting duplicates and determine if it's a flaw in your query. No one can tell you that, there's nothing syntactically wrong here, but it takes an understanding of the data and your use case. If you determine it's fine, yeah, then just add a DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is better to use GROUP BY for the columns you want in the resultset

```
select o.objectnumber,
       g.locale,
       g.locus,
       g.excavation, 
       g.mapreferencenumber,
       case when t.texttypeid like '9' then t.textentry end,
       case when f.userfieldid like '25' then f.fieldvalue end
       from objects o
       inner join TextEntries t on t.id = o.objectid
       inner join ObjGeography g on g.ObjectID = o.objectid
       inner join userfieldxrefs f on f.id = o.objectid
       inner join PackageList pl on o.objectID = pl.ID
       inner join Packages p on pl.PackageID = p.PackageID
       where p.packageid like '8502'
       group by   o.objectnumber,
       g.locale,
       g.locus,
       g.excavation, 
       g.mapreferencenumber,
       case when t.texttypeid like '9' then t.textentry end,
       case when f.userfieldid like '25' then f.fieldvalue end
       order by g.mapreferencenumber asc
```